# Text size modifier extending from a item to another

Tags: fontsize, itemize, size

I was wondering why is the large size modifier is extending from the first item to the end of the itemize, when it should stop on the closing bracket. This is what I mean: [image: https://i.imgur.com/HLrmjKJ.png]

```
\begin{itemize}
\item B2 certification (highest obtainable) for all 5 language skills \large{(listening, reading, spoken interaction, spoken production and writing)}.
\item Self assigned C1 for listening and writing skills.
\end{itemize}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: `\large` is a declaration, it does not have an argument.  Thus, proper scope-limiting use is `{\large ....}`, not `\large{...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, `\large` is a declaration, it does not have an argument. Thus, proper scope-limiting use is `{\large ...}`, not `\large{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item B2 certification (highest obtainable) for all 5 language skills
{\large(listening, reading, spoken interaction, 
  spoken production and writing)}.
\item Self assigned C1 for listening and writing skills.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]